# File descriptor set and selection understanding - unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, c, select, set, file-descriptor

I have a third party library for some kind of shared memory (between processes) implementation with some preset number of memory buffers.

Processes are divided into `reading` and `writing`.

This library gives a `file-descriptor` to each process.

I wanted to test the functionality, using some code sample (single process with divided reading and writing functionality) provided by the library. The code sample worked, but I wanted to understand what those file descriptors are and how they work.

This is the basic code sample (reduced and commented by me) (uses `4 shared buffers`):

```
int fd1, fd2; // 2 file descriptors, fd1 for writing and fd2 for reading

SharedMemory_GetDescriptor(&fd1, options1); // options1 tells the library that fd1 will be used for writing data
SharedMemory_GetDescriptor(&fd2, options2); // options2 tells the library that fd2 will be used for reading data

fd_set readset, writeset; // fd_sets for later select commands

// empty the sets
FD_ZERO(&readset);
FD_ZERO(&writeset);

// find out whether writer may write
FD_SET(fd1, &writeset);
FD_SET(fd2, &readset); // WHY HAS THIS ONE TO BE SET??

// test which sets are "ready to read or write"
select(Maxfd+1, &readset, &writeset, NULL, &timeout); // maxfd is 1 bigger than fd1 and fd2, timeout is some small time value...

// if fd1 is ready to write, we can 
if (FD_ISSET(fd1, &writeset)) 
{
   if (SharedMemory_GetBuffer(&buffer1) == S_OK) 
   {
       [...] // write some values to the buffer provided by the shared memory
       SharedMemory_ReleaseBuffer(&buffer1); // tell the library, that this buffer was written?!?
   }
}

// if I repeat the steps FD_SET(fd1, writeset)->select->FD_ISSET(fd1, &writeset)->fillBufferAndRelease,
// the FD_ISSET fails for the 5th buffer, since we only have 4 buffers. This result was expected and works.

// now try to read the data by using the second file descriptor fd2

// add fd2 to readset
FD_SET(fd2, &readset);
// test whether fd2 is ready to be read
select(Maxfd+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

if (FD_ISSET(fd2, &readset)) 
    {
        if (SharedMemory_GetBuffer(&buffer2) == S_OK) 
        {
            [...] // read data from buffer provided by the shared memory
       SharedMemory_ReleaseBuffer(&buffer2); // tell the library, that this buffer was read?!?
        }
    }
```

this works as expected, I can write to 1-4 buffers and later read from 1-4 buffers. Additionally I can e.g. first write one buffer, then read one, then write one and so on.

But there is something I didn't expect. From my understanding, before writing data in the beginning,

```
FD_SET(fd1, &writeset); 
FD_SET(fd2, &readset); 
select(Maxfd+1, &readset, &writeset, NULL, &timeout);
```

could be reduced to

```
FD_SET(fd1, &writeset); 
select(Maxfd+1, NULL, &writeset, NULL, &timeout);
```

because I'm neither interested in the readset before I WRITE data, nor is fd2 still in readset after the `select` returns.

but if I change to `select(Maxfd+1, NULL, &writeset, NULL, &timeout);` OR if I remove the `FD_SET(fd2, &readset);`, the `select` before the READING part waits until `timeout` and `fd2` isn't present in the `readset` anymore.

What can be the reasons for that?
As far as I seem to understand, whether fd1 and fd2 are ready-to-write or ready-to-read depends on some state of the extern library. But why does this library state change when I locally add fd2 to a set and ask it for being ready-to-read but it isn't?

Or am I misunderstanding something concerning those file-descriptors and `select`?? I am really noob in this topic and couldn't find much information/tutorials.

***EDIT***:

tried some more things:

- added a single `FD_SET(fd2, &readset); select(fd2+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);` before the first writeset-select and removed the readset part from the first writeset-select. This did work, but doesn't answer the question in any ways.
- changed the order of `getting the descriptors from the library` so that fd1 is the bigger number. Didn't change anything.
- changed `Maxfd` to be `fd1` or `fd2` in each select call (so the select is with fd1+1 or fd2+1 depending on whether it is used to catch read- or write-readiness) but this didn't change anything.